# How to validate data after update in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have two tables A and B which are not related.

```
SQL> select * from A;  

OLD_ID           R_ID  
---------- ----------  
TA-BC               1  
TB-BC               2  
TC-BC               3  
TD-BC               4  
TE-BC               5  
TF-BC               6  
TG-BC               7  
                    8  

SQL> select * from B;  


    NEW_ID OLD_ID     S_CD  
---------- ---------- -----  
         1 TA-BC      A  
         2 TB-BC      B  
         3 TC-BC      C  
         4 TD-BC      A  
         5 TE-BC      B  
         6 TF-BC      F  
         7 TG-BC      C  
         8 TH-BC      B
```

I need to update column "old_id" in table A with corresponding "new_id" values from table B where A.OLD_ID = B.OLD_ID.

I have written something like below. The data in table A and B has around 1 million records the one i gave above here is sample data. Since the data volume is high am updating for every 25k records and commiting it in a loop.

```
DECLARE  
  v_cnt number := 1;  
BEGIN  
 WHILE v_cnt > 0 LOOP  
   UPDATE /*+ parallel(A 10) */ A a  
   SET a.old_id =  
          (SELECT DISTINCT new_id  
             FROM B b  
            WHERE b.old_id = a.old_id)  
 WHERE     EXISTS  
              (SELECT 1  
                 FROM B b1  
                WHERE b1.old_id = a.old_id and ROWNUM < 25000;  
   v_cnt := SQL%ROWCOUNT;  
   COMMIT;  
 END LOOP;  
END;  
/
```

I would like to know how can i print how many records got updated and how can i  validate whether all the records in table A which has the matching record in table B with old_id has got updated correctly or not. What is the query i can write before/after the update statement to validate if table A "old_id" column  has been updated correctly with values from table B "new_id" columns

Below is the table creation script.

```
create table A(old_id varchar2(10),r_id number);  


insert into A values ('TA-BC',1);  
insert into A values ('TB-BC',2);  
insert into A values ('TC-BC',3);  
insert into A values ('TD-BC',4);  
insert into A values ('TE-BC',5);  
insert into A values ('TF-BC',6);  
insert into A values ('TG-BC',7);  
insert into A(r_id) values(8);  
commit;  


create table B(new_id number,old_id varchar2(10),s_cd varchar2(5));  

insert into B values (1,'TA-BC','A');  
insert into B values (2,'TB-BC','B');  
insert into B values (3,'TC-BC','C');  
insert into B values (4,'TD-BC','A');  
insert into B values (5,'TE-BC','B');  
insert into B values (6,'TF-BC','F');  
insert into B values (7,'TG-BC','C');  
insert into B values (8,'TH-BC','B');  
commit;
```

Comment: `R_ID` and `S_CD` are not needed to perform the update. Can you explain why they are included in your question? If they are not needed it's best to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you are *replacing* `OLD_ID` with `NEW_ID` when they are different data types: `OLD_ID` is char and `NEW_ID` is an integer.

It would be better to add a new field (column) to the table to store `NEW_ID` and update that.

You can then check the mapping of old to new has been performed correctly *and* take advantage of the fact the new id is the correct data type for joins to other tables using `NEW_ID`